# Division of two operators (or polonomials of operators) in quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, linear-algebra

Consider a function of an operator $\hat{A}$, which is like follows

$$ f\left(\hat{A}\right) = \frac{a + i b\hat{A}-c\hat{A}^2}{3-\hat{A}} $$

where $a$, $b$ and $c$  are complex numbers. My question is, what is the meaning of the operator in the denominator? Can I thing about it as an inverse operator? I mean

$$ \hat{A}^{-1} = \frac{1}{\hat{A}} $$

If that were so, could I, for example, multiply $f(\hat{A})$ on both sides by $3-\hat{A}$, and get only $a + i b\hat{A}-c\hat{A}^2$ on the RHS?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: typically you would define f by its polynomial/laurant series expansion

Comment: The answer to your question is yes. Note that in general that notation is misleading because "division" (i.e. multiplication by inverse) is not commutative but in this case everything commutes so that notation is allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, when we talk about any function of an operator $f(\hat{A})$ there are two ways to define it:

1. If $\hat{A}$ is diagonalizable with some basis of eigenstates $|a\rangle$ with eigenvalues $a$, then we define it via its operation in this basis $f(\hat{A}) = \sum_{a}|a\rangle f(a) \langle a|$, where we replaced the function of the operator with the function of the eigenvalue. This maintains $f(\hat{A})|a\rangle = f(a)|a\rangle$.
2. If $f(x)$ has a well defined power-series expansion $f(x) = \sum_n \lambda_n x^n$ then we can define the function of the operator via the power-series, where we know how to take integer non-negative powers of the operators (just multiple applications of it).

If both hold true (that is - $\hat{A}$ has a basis of eigenstates and $f(x)$ has a power series expansion) then they agree with each other. If only one of them is true then we are forced to use this definition, and if none of them is true then we might be in a problem and it is not altogether clear that what we write makes sense, and we might need to state more clearly what exactly is this thing that we wrote (not everything we can type autoamticaly has meaning).

Another important caveat is that if $\hat{A}$ and $\hat{B}$ do not commute, than writing something like
$$ f = \frac{\hat{A}-3}{\hat{B}+2i}$$ might be ill defined because one can interpret it both as $f = (\hat{A}-3)(\hat{B}+2i)^{-1}$ and as $f = (\hat{B}+2i)^{-1}(\hat{A}-3)$, which are different in general.